# JPA: Entity refreshing before commit

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions

How to refresh missing entity's references inside a same transaction where I will persist the entity? Now I get this error "No row with the given identifier exists: [this instance does not yet exist as a row in the database#27565]". I know that entity doesn't found from database before commit but I need those missing references to add acl entry for that entity.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide your entity model, I will write an example. You do not need refresh anything, you just add child to parent and save child.

```
 @Transactional
 public void createNewChild(Parent parent){

    Child child = new Child();
    child.setParent(parent);

    parent.getChildren.add(child);

    childDao.persist(child);

 }
```

Model of Parent:

```
 @Entity
 public class Parent{

    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Child> getChildren(){
       return this.children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Child> children){
       this.children = children;
    }

 }
```

In case you have set @Cascade attribute on Parent to persist and save_update you can save parent instead.